# Spring Cloud Gateway NullPointerException on LoadBalancerClientFilter while accessing lb:// url with eureka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, gateway, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to use spring -cloud gateway with spring boot 2.0.0.RC1 and springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.M5' . I get NullPointerException on LoadBalancerClientFilter .. 
The sample code can be found at https://github.com/jaysara/spring-cloud-gateway-example

The code does not have Eureka Server. I have a simple SpringBoot application with @EnableEurekaServer that runs the Eureka on port 8761 locally.

I can access the urls with /cf1 and /cf2. However when I say lb:// does not work.

Here is the stack trace

```
2018-02-07 10:16:43.121 ERROR 77327 --- [     parallel-2] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [GET http://localhost:8081/lb]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.LoadBalancerClientFilter.filter(LoadBalancerClientFilter.java:59) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$GatewayFilterAdapter.filter(FilteringWebHandler.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter.filter(OrderedGatewayFilter.java:40) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$DefaultGatewayFilterChain.filter(FilteringWebHandler.java:103) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter.filter(RouteToRequestUrlFilter.java:59) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$GatewayFilterAdapter.filter(FilteringWebHandler.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter.filter(OrderedGatewayFilter.java:40) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$DefaultGatewayFilterChain.filter(FilteringWebHandler.java:103) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter.filter(NettyWriteResponseFilter.java:52) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$GatewayFilterAdapter.filter(FilteringWebHandler.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter.filter(OrderedGatewayFilter.java:40) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$DefaultGatewayFilterChain.filter(FilteringWebHandler.java:103) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler.handle(FilteringWebHandler.java:87) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.SimpleHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleHandlerAdapter.java:62) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.invokeHandler(DispatcherHandler.java:168) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handle$1(DispatcherHandler.java:160) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) [reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:271) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:803) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1069) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) [reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.tryOnNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscriptionConditional.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:574) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscriptionConditional.request(FluxIterable.java:459) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:170) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:149) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103) [reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:124) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable.subscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3006) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:418) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) [reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1069) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:329) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1626) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:318) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3006) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.subscribe(MonoZip.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3006) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:141) [reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:97) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:271) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:803) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1069) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) [reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:104) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1626) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:170) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:156) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103) [reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterFuseable.subscribe(MonoFilterFuseable.java:47) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3006) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:418) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefaultIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoDefaultIfEmpty.java:37) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilter.subscribe(MonoFilter.java:46) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3006) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:167) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3006) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:78) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1628) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1440) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1314) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3006) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:773) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:543) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:523) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:409) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:254) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:190) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:332) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter.subscribe(FluxFilter.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilter.subscribe(MonoFilter.java:46) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) [reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1069) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replayNormal(FluxReplay.java:799) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replay(FluxReplay.java:892) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.ReplayProcessor$ReplayInner.request(ReplayProcessor.java:561) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:264) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:161) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:149) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:149) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.request(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103) [reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:179) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.ReplayProcessor.subscribe(ReplayProcessor.java:315) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6633) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.subscribe(MonoProcessor.java:434) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilter.subscribe(MonoFilter.java:46) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefaultIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoDefaultIfEmpty.java:37) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:148) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscriberContext.subscribe(MonoSubscriberContext.java:47) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) [reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:97) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnValue$ScheduledScalar.run(FluxSubscribeOnValue.java:170) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:50) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:27) ~[reactor-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: https://github.allstate.com/jsarl/spring-cloud-gateway-example is not public

Comment: try with snapshots, I think that may already be fixed.

Comment: I apologize. Posted a wrong URL. Here is the correct one, https://github.com/jaysara/spring-cloud-gateway-example

The issue is fixed now. I had a typo. I did not specify lb://. The BUILD-SNAPSHOT does not give me anything back even with lb:// . However Finchley.M5 seems to be working.